# GTK4: Picture does not shrink

Tags: gtk4

I am trying to insert an image into a header bar in GTK4. The image should fit the height of the parent widget. In gtk4-rs I tried:

```
let image = gtk::Picture::builder()
        .hexpand(false)
        .vexpand(false)
        .halign(gtk::Align::Fill)
        .valign(gtk::Align::Fill)
        .keep_aspect_ratio(true)
        .can_shrink(true)
        .build();
```

Although `can_shrink(true)` is set, the image causes the header to grow. I also tried `.height_request(1).width_request(1)`, but that also had no effect.

How can I make the image fit the header's size determined by the other widgets in the header?

Answer (score 0):

maybe it is too late but, have you tried setting the `content_fit` property with `gtk::ContentFit::ScaleDown`? To do that, you'd need to enable the feature `v4_8` on your Cargo.toml file like `gtk4 = { version = "0.6.6", features = ["v4_8"] }`